Equivalent to SQL trigger but codewise in c#
I need to create code wise in C# some sort of event listener, whose functionality will serve basically as a "SQL trigger".
For example, when a certain property is updated of an entity, trigger a method that will insert that updated property (value, dateInserted) in another table. I am trying to avoid to update in 10+ places where I call the update method of the entity, and right afterwards call my other defined method that will insert the update changes in the other table.
Triggers are recommended to be avoided as per the requirements, so that's why I need to take this approach.
Any help is appreciated.

"Triggers are recommended to be avoided as per the requirements" - what requirements?   Your design sounds somewhat wrong. If an entity changes, you save it back to the DB. What you are proposing will be a nightmare.

The requirements from the client. Maybe you did not understand me correct. When an entity changes, you update that entity and save it with the updated values in the DB. What I need is to target a certain column in that entity and see if it is changed or not, if it is changed, and saved back in the DB, do an insert with the changed value of that column in another table.

"What I need is to target a certain column in that entity and see if it is changed or not, if it is changed, and saved back in the DB, do an insert with the changed value of that column in another table." - that is precisely what a DB trigger should be used for!

I understand you bro, but I can't. If it was up to me I wouldn't be writing this post :)

The amount of bad software that is written to satisfy stupid client requirements......

@MitchWheat You should print that on a T-Shirt...

I'm assuming you're using an ORM of some sort? EF or EF Core, perhaps?

We are using Dapper ORM.

You almost certainly have an XY problem. Look at Change Tracking
